# There's something weird about my sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ddms

I have a table named `kategori` like this :

```
_id  |    nama
1    |    Percakapan Umum
2    |    Angka
```

And I try to SELECT with a simple query like this

`select * from kategori where nama = 'Angka'`

And it returns 0 rows as shown as this message

> 0 Rows returned from: select * 
>   from kategori
>   where nama = 'Angka'; (took 4ms)

All that I want is to show the second record with this query. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: how about `where trim(nama) = 'Angka';` ?

Comment: 0 Rows returned from: select * 
from kategori
where trim(nama) = ' Angka'; (took 4ms)

Comment: Why you are adding a space `' Angka'`, remove that space before the name.

Comment: I repaired my query and it also returns 0 rows too.

Comment: did you try `trim(nama) = 'Angka';` ?

Comment: I did..
0 Rows returned from: select * 
from kategori
where trim(nama) = 'Angka'; (took 4ms)
Is this something weird ?

Comment: yes in deed, could you post the table and some data on sqlfiddle.com it will be easy to see whats going wrong there.

Comment: test this and if returns something doubt about chars: `select * from kategori where nama = (select nama from kategori where _id = 2)`

Answer (score 0):

You have a space at the start of the value.

Change:

```
select * from kategori where nama = ' Angka'
```

to

```
select * from kategori where nama = 'Angka'
```

Leading spaces matter, but trailing ones do not.

See [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/39525)

Comment: Thanks, but your solution returns 0 rows too

Comment: Weird! Anything return from `select * from kategori where _id = 2;` ?

Comment: 1 Rows returned from: select * 
from kategori
where _id = 2 (took 4ms)

Comment: Maybe you have whitespace in your value. Try `where trim(nama) = 'Angka'`